# Printui.dll, PrintUIEntry for installing a driver on a remote machine

Tags: winapi, wmi, printers, network-printers, rundll32

In the help of `printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /?`, we have the following examples for remotely installing printer driver with the help of `/c` switch.

```
 Add printer driver using inf: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /c\\machine /m "Brother DCP-128C" /h "x86" /v "Type 3 - User Mode" /f c:\infpath\infFile.inf
   Add printer driver using inf: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /K /c\\machine /m "Brother DCP-128C" /h "x86" /v 3
```

I am failing in getting this to work with an error code of 0x32 (This function is not supported). I am doing the following :

1. Using "net use" to create a connection to the remote server using the remote server's admin credentials.
2. Disabling the UAC in the remote machine.
3. Running the above command with and without /K.

I can see that it is copying the driver files into the remote machines "print$" folder but the remote installation finally fails with an error prompt with error code of 0x32.

- Is there a way or a specific condition to make this thing work ? Because it is mentioned as an example in the help documentation, I think that I might be missing something.
- Are there any other ways to achieve the desired task?